# Jetty 12 Spring 6 missing Content-Length in response

Tags: java, spring, http, jetty

Jetty 12 with Spring 6 do not set in response `Content-Length` or `Transfer-Encoding:chunked` when using `HttpMessageConverter` (`GsonHttpMessageConverter` in my example) and client sends request with `Connection:close` header.

Here is a request to a simple servlet:

```
$ curl -v -X POST -H "Connection:close" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:1221/abc/simple
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:1221...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 1221 (#0)
> POST /abc/simple HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:1221
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> Connection:close
> Content-Type: application/json
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Jetty(12.0.2)
< Date: Mon, 15 Jan 2024 19:16:17 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 2
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
{}
```

Compare with a request to Spring controller which uses `HttpMessageConverter`:

```
$ curl -v -X POST -H "Connection:close" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"input":"aaa"}' http://localhost:1221/abc/controller/
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:1221...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 1221 (#0)
> POST /abc/controller/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:1221
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> Connection:close
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 15
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Jetty(12.0.2)
< Date: Mon, 15 Jan 2024 19:16:52 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
{"msg":"aaa"}
```

No `Content-Length` or `Transfer-Encoding:chunked` in response. But one of them should be there according to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.4.

Also I tried Jetty 11 Spring5/6, Jetty 9 Spring 4 - same results.

See example in https://github.com/techsup69/jetty-cont-len-12 for Jetty12 Spring 6.

Somebody knows why is Jetty/Spring acting like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC2616 is obsolete.

Jetty 12 defaults to RFC7230 behaviors when it comes to HTTP/1.x behaviors.

Now to what's happening, since you specified `Connection: close` on the request, that means the `Connection: close` on the response is the indication that the response body is complete once the connection is closed.

*This is mentioned in [paragraph 2 of Section 3 of RFC7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3).*

If you do not specify `Connection: close` you will get the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` to satisfy the persistent connection requirements.

This behavior (called a "close-delimited message") has been consistent in Jetty for quite a number of years.  But should it still do that?  Probably not in light of [RFC7230 section 3.3.3 Message Body Length](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3).

So I opened https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/11277

Answer (score 1):

Jetty already does make every attempt to avoid using EOF delimitation for messages.

In this case the client is actually requesting that `Connection: close` be used and by latest [RFC9112 9.6 Tear Down](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9112#name-tear-down), this is still valid for `HTTP/1.1`.

However, even in this case, if Jetty has been told the `content-length` or can infer it from how the request was written, then it will [use it](https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/blob/jetty-12.0.5/jetty-core/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpGenerator.java#L728-L739) as well as `Connection: close`.

So in this case, the response must be being flushed before there is either a `content-length` set or all the content has been written.   I guess potentially Jetty could then use chunking delimitation with `Connection:close`? We will look into that, but that will just cover over an inefficient generation of content.